# The order of loading locations in Spring @ContextConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, configuration, liquibase

I'm using the following configuration for my db integration test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring/spring-master.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
@Transactional()
public class EmployeeAccessPropertyTest {
```

**spring-master.xml** loads spring config files in the following order:

```
<import resource="classpath:spring/db/dev-datasource-config.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:spring/db/jpa-config.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:spring/db/transaction-config.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:spring/db/component-config.xml"/>
```

**dev-datasource-config.xml** defines dataSource and initializes db scheme via liquibase:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/config/dev-data-access.properties"/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml" />
    <property name="dropFirst" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Now, when I run test, I'm getting the following error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: studentPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: employees
```

It seems, table is not created when entityManagerFactory is initialized (in the **jpa-config.xml** file). Ok, I generate scheme via liquibase maven plugin first:

```
mvn initialize liquibase:update
```

Comment the following db scheme generation via Spring context:

```
<!--<bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">-->
    <!--<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />-->
    <!--<property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml" />-->
    <!--<property name="dropFirst" value="true" />-->
<!--</bean>-->
```

And the problem is gone. What can I do to make sure that Spring first loads dev-datasource-config.xml, initializes the liquibase bean and only then loads jpa-config.xml where which looks like:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'depends-on' attribute, as described in spring manual:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-dependson

E.g.

```
<bean id="beanOne" class="ExampleBean" depends-on="manager"/>

<bean id="manager" class="ManagerBean" />
```